# Lightbox constantly displaying in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, lightbox, moodle

I'm running Moodle 2.9.1 and I have a terms & conditions lightbox displaying correctly under every major browser (IE11, Chrome, Opera, Firefox). However, when i run it in IE9 the lightbox just keeps popping, even when i click the button to not see it again. I have tried to go through Moodle's configuration settings up and down and I don't seem to find any answer.

Any suggestions? thanks!!